# Voltage gain from AC

Tags: voltage, ac, gain, matlab

## Voltage gain CE & CC from AC

Can you tell me please if I am true in calculation of gain of this circuit?

Assumption: gm is known and beta=inf, Early VA=inf => gbe=0, gce=0.

[image]
[image]
**Here the Matlab code :**

```
clear
clc
syms gm gs g1 g2 g3 g4 vo v3 v1 vi
a(1)=(v3-vo)*gm==0;
a(2)=gm*v1==v3*g4;
a(3)=(vi-(-v1))*gs==-v1*(g1+g2);
v=solve(a,vo,v3,v1)
av=v.vo/vi
```

[image]

Thanks!

---

## Voltage gain CE & CC from AC without capacitor to R3

What about this equation ?

[image]
[image]

**Here the Matlab code with only 3 equations about the first stage because the 2nd gives av=1 :**

```
clearvars
syms gm gs g1 g2 g3 g4 vo v3 vi va ve
v1=ve-va;
a(1)=gm*v1==v3*g4;
a(2)=ve*g3+gm*v1==0;
a(3)=(vi-va)*gs==va*(g1+g2);
v=solve(a,v3,ve,va);
avWithoutC2=v.v3/vi
```

[image]

Thank You very much !

Comment: Well the first stage gain is \$ - \frac{R_1||R_2}{R_S + R_1||R_2} \times g_{m1}R_4\$, thus, your equation is correct

Comment: Thank You very much G36 ! Your analyse is more easy. Like cc stage gives av = 1 a look about the first stage is better.

Comment: What do you think of the other equation without capacitor ?

Comment: Without the cap, the input signal will now be divided thus the gain will be lower. Previously the gain was \$g_mR_C\$ but now the gain is \$\frac{R_C}{\frac{1}{g_m} + R_E} =  \frac{g_m R_C}{1 + g_m R_E} =  \frac{g_m g_e}{g_c g_e + g_c g_m}=\frac{g_m g_e}{g_c(g_e + g_m)}\$ which means that you've got the correct result once more, good job. But I never was a big fan of using "conductance" instead of "resistance". And I always preferred the express the gain as a ratio of two resistors.

Comment: Thank You very much G36. It is a pleasure to communicate with you.